# writing tensorflow federated aggregation function (e.g., tff.federated_mean)

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I was trying to write a custom aggregation function for federated averaging. replacing 'federated_mean' seems to be very complex and the code is very hard to decipher. Is there any documentation/examples about those "intrinsics"? (called that way in the code)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in TFF!

Long-term, we are definitely planning on exposing the ability to write user-defined intrinsics in a simple way, but we are not quite there yet.

To implement custom aggregations, however, we provide the [`tff.federated_aggregate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_aggregate?hl=en) intrinsic, a generalized hierarchical aggregation function which takes five parameters:

- Value, of type `{T}@C`, the federated dataset to be aggregated.
- Zero, of type `U`, representing the zero in the reduction algebra.
- Accumulate, a function of type `<U,T> -> U`, which will be used to pointwise reduce the federated dataset. Accumulate materializes a set of values of type `U` at an intermediate level of the hierarchy.
- Merge, a function of type `<U,U> -> U`, used in a manner analogous to accumulate, except now materializing a single value of type `U` at the top level of the hierarchy.
- Report, a function of type `U -> R`, used to perform any final calculation on the aggregated values. For example, a federated mean could be implemented by accumulating and merging sums of the value, along with counts of the number of clients, and then dividing the sum by the count in the report step.

The result of calling the federated aggregate with these five parameters is a value of type `R@S`.

The documentation linked above has further discussion of `federated_aggregate` itself. For an example of how this can be used to write new aggregations, check out [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/eab9764f9c057aae39b60a8a4908826ad248a08c) implementing `federated_min` and `federated_max`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! I missed the importance of federated_aggregate I'll check it out. Still, I got to ask, is there anything simpler than map-reduce style? I get it's needed for real world performance but before thinking about real world I would like to experiment with things like trimmed-mean / quantiles that do not exactly transfer well to map-reduce.

Comment: BTW I ended up just returning the full federated_map in the training step and computing the aggregation with normal numPy

Comment: I think this is a reasonable approach. TFF can be thought of as a domain-specific language for specifying federated computations--and as such the computational model of the network is to some degree baked in, or at least there is an interaction between what is viewed as "deployable" and what TFF considers "natively expressible". Because of this, I think TFF's recommended way of simulating "new" network execution models is to *do it at the Python level*, which it seems is what you have discovered. You may also consider the use of `federated_collect` for this purpose.